# Joining Custom flat table with EAV table not Working

Tags: magento-1.8, custom, database, join

I am Joining two tables by following code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('commission/commission')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('customer' => $collection->getTable('customer/customer')),
        'main_table.customer_id = customer.id');
```

commission/commission is my custom module and flat table. that contain customer_id.

I am getting Error like this

```
Can't retrieve entity config: customer/customer
```

I am not understanding what is happening, Please suggest anything wrong,
Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're trying to get the table name from the commissions collection. Try and get the table name from the **core/resource** model. Simply replace:

```
$collection->getTable('customer/customer')
```

With

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer/customer')
```

Comment: No I am not getting it properly, Same error:[

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
         $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
             array('commission' => $collection->getTable('commission/commission')),
             'e.entity_id = commission.customer_id');    By above change now it say's **Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id "41" already exist**

Comment: how to add duplicate entity_id in collection, Now, I got to know that if entity_id already exist in collection then magento throw this error, Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: @Charlie try grouping them on the entity_id **->group('entity_id')** on your join